# jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.JMSSampler: Unable to connect to the target queue manage

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, ruby-jmeter

I am running the smoke suite on Jmeter with WMQ and IMA set Up. I am facing an issue where after running the suite say for eg 10 mins rest of the samplers( Jms Subscriber,Jms Point to Point) are failing because of below error code:

2015/08/31 13:18:07 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.JMSSampler: Unable to connect to the target queue manager 172.18.14.115:1419/VJT.CLIENT.SMH javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Unable to connect to the target queue manager 172.18.14.115:1419/VJT.CLIENT.SMH [Root exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2009
MQJE016: MQ queue manager closed channel immediately during connect
Closure reason = 2009]
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.context.MQContext.(MQContext.java:196)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.context.WMQInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WMQInitialContextFactory.java:29)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.JMSSampler.getInitialContext(JMSSampler.java:424)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.JMSSampler.threadStarted(JMSSampler.java:319)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:597)
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:961)
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:946)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:566)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:554)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2009
MQJE016: MQ queue manager closed channel immediately during connect
Closure reason = 2009
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:212)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11._createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:318)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:338)
    at com.ibm.mq.StoredManagedConnection.(StoredManagedConnection.java:84)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQSimpleConnectionManager.allocateConnection(MQSimpleConnectionManager.java:168)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.obtainBaseMQQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:772)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.procure(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:697)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.constructQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:657)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.createQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:153)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.(MQQueueManager.java:451)
    at com.ibm.mq.pcf.PCFAgent.connect(PCFAgent.java:240)
    at com.ibm.mq.pcf.PCFAgent.(PCFAgent.java:174)
    at com.ibm.mq.pcf.PCFMessageAgent.(PCFMessageAgent.java:142)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.context.MQContext.(MQContext.java:183)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mqservices.MQInternalException: MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2009
MQJE016: MQ queue manager closed channel immediately during connect
Closure reason = 2009

we are unable to get the root cause, Can anyone please suggest the reason.

Answer (score 0):

we got the root cause of this issue, it is not because of Jmeter but because WMQ properties MAXINST & MAXINSTC for all the channels They were set to 25 that's why we are not able to establish the connection with WMQ after 25 request.

So we increased the size to 150 and the issue got resoved.